# Golang set a maps key as a variable for its value

Tags: mysql, go

I need to go through an html forms input values and place them into an mysql datbase. Which I'm currently using `r.Form` to get a map. So that i don't have to use `r.Form.Get("date")` for each which works but when i try to put the values into a database. It compiles just fine but i get `sql: converting argument #0's type: unsupported type []string, a slice` after i click submit in the browser. I can get around this by doing

```
`date := strings.Join(m["date"], "")`
```

but doing that for 30+ values especially since some of the submited values will be created from previous database entries using html templates. If i have to change or add more later seems like there must be a more efficient way I've seen `for key, val := range m {}` but unfortunately I've only been doing this for about a week and i can't figure out how to keep the values and change the variable they get set to after each iteration. So that after

```
for key, val := range m {
x := m[key]
}
```

so that it will put out the equivalent

```
keyname := keyvalue
```

changing the keyname each time to be the same as the keyname in the map ie

```
date := 2015-8-13
time := 18:56:11
```

or if there's an easier way around this error then to create a varible for each one.

Comment: Could you please post a bit more code that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Maybe you should be using https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormValue, if you are sure that there's only ever going to be one value for each key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An HTML form can have multiple values for a single key. This is why the request form field is defined to be a map of string slices. The [request Form](http://godoc.org/net/http#Request.Form) is declared as

```
 Form url.Values
```

and [url.Values](http://godoc.org/net/url#Values) is declared as

```
  type Values map[string][]string
```

You can access the first value for a key using:

```
   var value string
   if values := req.Form[key]; len(values) > 0 {
      value = values[0]
   }
```

The [url.Values Get](http://godoc.org/net/url#Values.Get) helper method simplifies this code to:

```
   value := req.Form.Get(key)
```

The [http.Request FormValue](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormValue) helper method simplifies it a bit more:

```
  value := req.FormValue(key)
```

You iterate through keys and values using:

```
  for key, values := range req.Form {
     for _, value := range values {
         fmt.Println(key, value)
     }
  }
```

If you want to iterate over the first value for a key, then use this code:

```
 for key, values := range req.Form {
    if len(values) > 0 {
       value := values[0]
       fmt.Println(key, value)
    }
 }
```

Before accessing req.Form, call [req.ParseForm](http://godoc.org/net/http#Request.ParseForm) to parse the query string and request body.